# move object from nested array to another array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I need to move all my selected objects from one nested array to another on button click. My data structure is:

```
  const Data = [
    {
      name: "Steel Support, Aviation Lights, Std", // match parent array name
      code: "450W0619P001",
      reserved: [
        { serial: "one", selected: true }, // move all selected: true items to consumed array
        { serial: "two", selected: true },
      ],
      consumed: [],
    },
    {
      name: "Lock Nut, Prevailing Torque, M12x1.75m", // match parent array name
      code: "450W0619P001",
      reserved: [
        { serial: "one", selected: true },
        { serial: "two", selected: true },
        { serial: "three", selected: false },
      ],
      consumed: [],
    },
  ];

  const [erpParts, setErpParts] = useState(Data);
```

To achieve this I've written the following function:

```
const markConsumed = (parentArr) => {
    setErpParts((erpParts) =>
      erpParts.map((x) => {
        if (x.name !== parentArr.name) return x;
        else {
          const consumedUpdated = x.consumed;
          const reservedUpdated = x.reserved.map((res) => {
            if (res.selected == true) {
              return consumedUpdated.push(res), x.reserved.splice(res, 1);
            }
          });
          return { ...x, reserved: reservedUpdated, consumed: consumedUpdated };
        }
      })
    );
  };
```

Unfortunately my function is not returning the desired result. This is how I am calling the function:

```
<Button onPress={()=> markConsumed(activePart)}>MARK CONSUMED</Button>
```

Please look into this and let me know the issue in my function. In the expected result I need to move all selected parts from reserved array to consumed array like this:

```
const Data = [
    {
      name: "Steel Support, Aviation Lights, Std", // match parent array name
      code: "450W0619P001",
      reserved: [],
      consumed: [
      { serial: "one", selected: true }, // parent array name matched and moved selected items from reserved to consumed array
      { serial: "two", selected: true },
     ],
    },
    {
      name: "Lock Nut, Prevailing Torque, M12x1.75m",
      code: "450W0619P001",
      reserved: [
        { serial: "one", selected: true },
        { serial: "two", selected: true },
        { serial: "three", selected: false },
      ],
      consumed: [],
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a basic loop, and push think where it should belong.

```js
const Data = [{ name: "Steel Support, Aviation Lights, Std", code: "450W0619P001", reserved: [{ serial: "one", selected: true }, { serial: "two", selected: true },], consumed: [], }, { name: "Lock Nut, Prevailing Torque, M12x1.75m", code: "450W0619P001", reserved: [{ serial: "one", selected: true }, { serial: "two", selected: true }, { serial: "three", selected: false },], consumed: [], },];

function markConsumedAndUpdate(filterName) {
    return Data.map(item => {
        if (item.name != filterName) return item
        let reserved = []
        for (const elem of item.reserved)
            if (!elem.selected)
                reserved.push(elem)
            else
                item.consumed.push(elem);

        item.reserved = reserved;
        return item
    });
}
markConsumedAndUpdate("Steel Support, Aviation Lights, Std")
markConsumedAndUpdate("Lock Nut, Prevailing Torque, M12x1.75m")

console.log(Data)
```

Comment: thanks Nur. it is working but not as expected. when I try to use the same function and update the consumed array it instead of pushing new items from reserved, replaces all old items. I need to push items from reserved to consumed. use case is user will be selecting the items from reserved and once he click the button we will be moving marked items to consumed.

Comment: does this answer you question? or I missed something?

Comment: no. I need to push the selected items into reserved array where in your function when I click the button with function, it is replacing all old items in reserved array

Comment: please see if you could update the function based on the use case

Comment: why not you just push item? wait a sec... I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks Nur. this is the same functionality I was expecting. only thing is this function is not resetting the state when I move back & forward to another screens. I need to mutate the state and show the result only till I am at the same screen. Please see if you could update again.

Comment: In this case, I thinks this is an XY problem. Can You provide more context about it?

Comment: Sure, I am learning react native and in this functionality user will be able to select items from reserved array. Once the items are selected we will be pushing them into consumed array. Your function was working fine apart from it is not mutating the react state. Ideally if I move away from the screen it should return the original state

Comment: Can you look into my function and see if I missed something. const markConsumed = (parentArr) => {
    setErpParts((erpParts) =>
      erpParts.map((x) => {
        if (x.name !== parentArr.name) return x;
        else {
          const consumedUpdated = x.consumed;
          const reservedUpdated = x.reserved.map((res) => {
            if (res.selected == true) {
              return consumedUpdated.push(res), x.reserved.splice(res, 1);
            }
          });
          return { ...x, reserved: reservedUpdated, consumed: consumedUpdated };
        }
      })
    );
  };